# Can a UITabBarController be used with multiple handles to the same view?

Tags: ios

I have some data that is to be displayed in a table view, the data to be displayed can be filtered by 3 criteria and the user will select those criteria using a tab bar.

Is it possible for me to create one instance of a table view controller and when the user clicks on a tab the table view's data content gets filtered - rather than having to create 3 separate instances of the table view controller and set the tab bar controller view controllers array to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you should be able to set the same controller for more than one tab but that's really not likely to work very well since the transition from the controller to itself when you touch a button is really not something the controller lifecycle was intended to do. You'd also have to jump through hoops to figure out which button was selected.

The standard way to do this would be to use a UISegmentedControl to select what the controller was showing.